# Forming a set of positive integers with each subset summing uniquely

Tags: elementary-set-theory, summation

Let N be a positive integer.

We want a set of positive integers M, |M| = N, such that any subset sums to a unique number.

In general there may be a lot of numbers. Setting each number to 1, and we couldn't distinguish which 1's added up to, say, 3.  If M is powers of 2, then that may work (for N=3):

M = {1,2,4}

```
1
2
4
1+2=3
4+1=5
4+2=6
4+1+2=7
```

The problem is now the numbers use more bits. Can we do it in less bits?

Comment: Any singleton $M = \{k\}$ satisfies this condition. Also a pedantic point: I think you technically mean any *nonempty* subset. The empty set would yield the empty sum, which is 0. In that case, only $M = \emptyset$ would work. Also, you can reach any $N$ via the same procedure you wrote: $M =\{1, \dots, 2^{N-1}\}$.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop I think what's wanted here is no two subsets have the same sum.

Comment: It seems nearly obvious that powers of two are the smallest such set of numbers.  In particular, they are those numbers which require a maximum multiple of one on each to achieve every consecutive integer up to the maximum possible...  In other words, any set of numbers which is "smaller" than the powers of two must contain some repeat sum.

Comment: And since there are exactly $2^M$ subsets...

Comment: Note that if you are going for compression of such a set that uses the powers of $2$, you can just use the exponent $M$ from $2^M-1$, and when you want the set back you build up the powers of two from $0$ to $M-1$ as a set.

Answer (score 2):

You can always build one incrementally like below:

- Let begin with $S_0=\varnothing$
- Chose a number $a_{n+1}$ strictly greater than $\sum\limits_{i\in S_n} a_i$
- Define $S_{n+1}=S_n\cup\{a_{n+1}\}$

Then $S_N$ satisfies your request.

Note that in case of base-$2$ numbers, you start with $1$, select $2>1$ then $4>1+2$ then $8>1+2+4$, and so on... At each step you have selected the minimal number available, so base-$2$ numbers will give the minimal $\max(S_N)$ for a given $N$.

Comment: I want to add that this is a sufficient condition, it is not a necessary condition. For instance the sets for $N=4$ given by $\{1,2,4,8\}$ and $\{1001,1002,1004,1008\}$ both lead to valid sets, while the second one does not verify my construction.